# Linking pages in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, sitepages, quick-links

What is the best way to link from one SharePoint page (using Quick Links) to another?

I ask this as I am sure when the pop up screen displayed with what you can link to (Recent, Stock Images, OneDrive etc.), the site option listed the site pages, but I can only see "Documents" and "Site Assets".

So I have to copy the URL of the page I want to link to and paste that in the "From a Link" option.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same behavior in all SharePoint sites.

So, you have to add the link to site page using **From a link** option only.

---

Additionally, if you see the site page in **Recent** tab, you can add it from their as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what happens when you click on 'site' though?  I would have thought the site pages folder would reside there?

Comment: I can see the document libraries (except Site Pages) on my SharePoint site when I clicked on "Site".

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, that's very helpful.

Comment: Great, glad it helped for you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.